# two same function on one single page how to execute one in php

Tags: php, logic

a bit tricky question I am unable to find any logic to apply, or maybe I am just missing something,
I made a separate file which define my functions, and then I included it on top so where ever i need I may conveniently run functions.

so after the `function.php`

I have a `index.php` in which I included several other files for example,

```
otherred.php
otherblue.php
etc.php
etc.php
```

I have a function that is

```
<?php
function my_revboxes($prv, $rnm, $postid, $mdetect){
if(isset($prv) && isset($rnm) && isset($mdetect)) {
if ($mdetect == 'redrav'){
$midv = 'pcom';
}
if ($mdetect == 'bluerav'){
$midv = 'pcomr';
}
if($prv !="" && $prv != "Text here" && $rnm !="") {
$usermeta = $rnm;
$posrav=get_post_meta($postid,$midv,true);
$posrav=$prv;
add_post_meta($postid,$midv,$posrav);
add_meta_user($usermeta, $posrav);
}
}

?>
<form method='POST' action="">
<textarea name=posrav value="" required placeholder ="If you are Agree please write your thoughts here"></textarea>
<?php
my_custom_field(); 
file_nameecho(); //detects if its otherred.php or otherblue.php
?>
<input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

this function is used on both files `otherred.php` and `otherblue.php`

the function `file_nameecho();` detects if its otherred or otherblue and generate `$mdetect` accordingly so it can put the comment on right side that is either red side or blue side, everything is working fine & fantastic.

but the only problem is the function is running two time, because its included in both files red and blue, and these both files are included in the main file.

I don't want to go and create separate function for each of them, is there any logic can be applied that it only execute one time, or only execute on the given page or according to `$mdetect` ?

tried include_once and require_once still not working.

Comment: Change to using `include_once()`, so that the file will be included/executed only once.

Comment: The most immediate way to fix this would be to use a global variable as a flag that says "This function has been run" - 
But that is not good practice, and we would not be doing you justice by teaching you how to do that. 

Instead, I suggest you look into OOP in php and put your functions into a class -

Comment: can you suggest something rm-vanda

Answer (score 0):

> but the only problem is the function is running two time, because its included in both files red and blue,

Please meet [include_once](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.include-once.php) and [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: it isn't helping at all ?
<?php require_once 'leftsiderev.php';?>

<?php require_once 'rightsiderev.php';?>

tried with include once too